# Flash iPhone app pixelated once displayed on iPhone4

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3

I have made the app in the larger resolution for iPhone4, and when I test it in 3GS it works/looks fine, the app scales DOWN accordingly. But when I test app on iPhone 4 it appears for reason to scale it down and then back up again creating a pixelated look. This applies to vector assets and text within the flash project as well which is even weirder in my opinion. My SWF is 640x920px.

Comment: how are you running flash on an iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3359843) support for retina-display graphics is not yet supported. The two output sizes are either low-resolution iPhone or iPad. To wit:

> The current version of PFI produces apps that run at 320x480 on iphones and ipods or 1024x768 on ipads. Support for 964x480 is something we're looking into adding for a future release.

Comment: Very useful information. I've been googling but cannot find any ETA in terms of when Adobe would launch an updated packager. Has anybody found/seen/heard any indication?